# break statement doesn't work in a loop

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, break

I saw a tutorial that explaining how to use the "break" statement in a loop
but every time i'm trying to use it i'm getting a compilation error saying:

> "break statement not within loop or switch
>                           `break;"`

This is my code:

```
if (finalFirstChar > 6 || finalFirstChar < 1)
{
    printf("You didn't entered a proper number! \n");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: read the compilation error

Comment: if  <-- not a loop :/

Comment: "If" is a single selection statement, not a loop...

Comment: Your loop doesnt work because loop is missing

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, `if` is a condition (*selection statement*, to be exact), and `break` works in a loop (*iteration statement*)/switch-case statement.

As per `C11`, chapter §6.8.6.3

> A `break` statement shall appear only in or as a switch body or loop body.

In any case, you don't need a `break` in a `if` statement body.

Comment: More precisely, you don't need a `break` in a `if` statement body, unless that `if` statement is itslef inside a loop body (or a switch case but that's not the subject)

Comment: I want to make this break so if the condition in the "if" does exist, it will skip to the end of the function and won't preform anything else in it.

Comment: @Nathan1982 for that you don't need break. Just negate the check in the condition and put the _rest_ part in the condition body. Simple.

Comment: @Nathan1982: you might also be confusing `break` and `return`.

Comment: whatever you end up doing, don't do go to

Comment: There are places, (not many places), where a goto is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

OK:

```
while (cond1) {
    if (cond2) break;                /* or continue; */
    if (cond3) return [something];
}

for (init; cond4; after) {
    if (cond5) break;                /* or continue; */
    if (cond6) return [something];
}

do {
    if (cond7) break;                /* or continue; */
    if (cond8) return [something];
} while (cond9);

if (cond10) return [something];
```

NOT OK:

```
if (cond11) {    /* not in any while/do/for loop, or case switch */
    break;                /* or continue; */
}
```